# Как искать по нескольким словам?

Tags: search, google-spreadsheet

Есть много строк в столбце, нужно отфильтровать строки убрав из выдачи те, которые содержат определенные слова.
К примеру =SEARCH(AND("*купить*";"*цена*");A2:A6738) не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение

Похоже, речь идет об инструменте Таблиц [фильтре или режиме фильтрации](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=ru). Проще всего использовать регулярное выражение для записи пользовательской формулы

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A; "(?i)(купить|цена)"))
```

или

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("*купить*";A:A));ISERROR(SEARCH("*цена*";A:A)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общей сложности фильтры работают так

```
=FILTER(A:A;NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A; "(?i)(купить|цена)"));A:A<>"")

=FILTER(
  A:A;
  ISERROR(SEARCH("*купить*";A:A));
  ISERROR(SEARCH("*цена*";A:A));
  A:A<>""
)
```

Или общий случай для списка

```
=FILTER(
  A:A;
  NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A; "(?i)(" & JOIN("|"; {"купить";"цена"}) & ")"));
  A:A<>""
)
```

---

А вообще, если дан список в диапазоне `'Данные'!A2:F`. То

### Данные, которые отсутствуют в списке

Список находится в `I2:I6`

```
=FILTER('Данные'!A2:F;ISNA(MATCH('Данные'!B2:B;I2:I6;0)))
```

### Данные, которые находятся в заранее заданном списке

Список `{"Георгий";"Ермак";"Юлиус"}`

```
=FILTER('Данные'!A2:F;NOT(ISNA(MATCH('Данные'!B2:B;{"Георгий";"Ермак";"Юлиус"};0))))
```

### Данные, которые соответствуют “нечеткому” списку значений

Список находится в `I2:I6`
Настраивается через регулярное выражение формулы `REGEXMATCH`

```
=FILTER('Данные'!A2:F;REGEXMATCH('Данные'!B2:B; "(?i)(" & JOIN("|"; I2:I6) & ")"))
```

Подробное применение `FILTER` и примеры на [contributor.pw](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-formulas-filter/#%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Comment: Функция FILTER выводит данные в определенной зоне таблицы, а как сделать не вывод, а только показ строк со скрытием тех которые содержат определенные слова? В Google Таблицы есть фильтр "Текст не содержит" где по одному параметру работает, а если нужно по двум параметрам то нет.  Функция SEARCH тоже хорошо работает с одним параметром, но с двумя не хочет как условие не ставь.

Comment: @Алексей, может быть вы тогда это опишите в вопросе? А лучше задайте уже новый.